# PostgreSQL indexed columns choice

Tags: postgresql, multi-index

I have these two tables :

```
CREATE TABLE ref_dates(
    date_id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    month int NOT NULL,
    year int NOT NULL,
    month_name CHAR(255)
);


CREATE TABLE util_kpi(
    kpi_id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    kpi_description int NOT NULL,
    kpi_value float,
    date_id int NOT NULL,
    dInsertion timestamp default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    CONSTRAINT fk_ref_kpi FOREIGN KEY (date_id) REFERENCES ref_dates(date_id)
);
```

Usually, the type of request i'd do is :

- Selecting `kpi_description` and `kpi_value` for a specified `month` and `year`:

```
SELECT kpi_description, kpi_value FROM util_kpi u JOIN ref_dates r ON u.date_id = r.date_id WHERE month=X AND year=XXXX
```

- Selecting `kpi_description` and `kpi_value` for a specified `kpi_description`, `month` and `year`:

```
SELECT kpi_description, kpi_value FROM util_kpi u JOIN ref_dates r ON u.date_id = r.date_id WHERE month=X AND year=XXXX AND kpi_description='XXXXXXXXXXX'
```

I tought about creating these indexes :

```
CREATE INDEX idx_ref_date_year_month ON ref_dates(year, month);
CREATE INDEX idx_util_kpi_date ON util_kpi(date_id);
```

First of all, i want to know if it's a good idea to create these indexes.

Second of all and finally, I was wondering if it's a good idea to add `kpi_description` to the indexes on `util_kpi` table.

Can you guys give me your opinion ?

Regards

Comment: [Edit] the question and show the queries in question verbatim, not just a vague description.

Comment: Is there a particular reason why you don't store dates as dates, but in a separate table with an id? Are date entities shared?

Comment: @stickybit Done, Bergi multiple rows of util_kpi may have the same date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible to give exact answer without looking on data.

So it's only possible to give an opinion.

### A. ref_dates

This table looks very similar to date dimension in ROLAP-schemas.

So the first what I would do: is change `date_id` from `SERIAL` to:

- `DATE` datatype
- or even "smart integer": integer datatype but in form YYYYMMDD. E.g. 20210430. It may look strange but it's not uncommon to see such identificators in date dimensions

The main point in using such form is that `date_id` in fact tables became informative even without joining to date dimension.

### B. util_kpi

I suppose that:

- `ref_dates` is a date dimension. So it's ~365 * number of years rows. It could be populated once for 20-30 years for future and it's still will not be really big
- `util_kpi` is fact table. Which must be big like "really big" - millions and more records.

For `util_kpi' I expected id of time dimension but did not found it. So no hourly stats are supposed yet.

I see `util_kpi.dInsertion` - which I suppose is planned to be used as time dimension. I would think to extract it into time_id where put hours, minutes and seconds (if milliseconds are not needed).

### C.Indexing

- `ref_dates`: it does not matters a lot how you index `ref_dates` because it's a relatively small table. Maybe unique index on `date_id` with `INCLUDE` options for all fields would be the best. Don't create individual index for fields with low selectivity like year or month - it will not make much sense but it will not harm a lot too.
- `util_kpi` - you need an index on `date_id` (as for any foreign keys to other dimension tables that will appear in future).

That's my thoughts that based on what I supposed.